# VMware workstation 10 on Ubuntu 14.04.04 - Virtual Network error

Tags: software-installation, vmware-workstation

VMware workstation is not working in my system. It is throwing virtual network device error.

OS- Ubuntu 14.04.04

kernel- Linux version 4.2.0-35-generic

[image: Error pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

## service vmware start

Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                     - done /
   Virtual machine communication interface     - done /
   VM communication interface socket family    - done /
   Blocking file system                        - done /
   Virtual ethernet                            - failed /
   VMware Authentication Daemon                - done

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but none from other suggestions in this forum worked for me apart from installing the latest version of VMware player. The sequence of commands is as follows:

- Uninstall current version: `sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player`
- Download the latest version of VMware Workstation Player (freeware for non-commercial use).
- Change mode of the installation file that you downloaded: `chmod +x VMware-Player-*.bundle`
- Install vmware player: `sudo ./VMware-Player-*.bundle`